# Download file by URL

Tags: c#, image, selenium

I am trying to download a file using the following piece of code.
Basically this is a Selenium project but I couldn't find any source of how to download an image using Selenium - C#.

Here is a piece of code I have tried but it didn't work.
Either with the `blob:` or without it.
I have managed to download the file with this code, but apparently removing the `blob:` somehow caused a corrupted `jpg` file .

```
 public static string SaveImage(string src, string fileName)
    {
        src = src.Replace("blob:", "");
        var pathToImage = $@"{folderPath}\{fileName}.jpg";
        using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
        {
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(src, pathToImage);
        }

        return pathToImage;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try visiting the url yourself?

Comment: Yes. Works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void DonwloadImage(string URL, string FileName)
{
   System.IO.StreamWriter SW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FileName);
   SW.Write(New System.Net.Http.HttpClient().GetStringAsync(URL).Result;
   SW.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an empty image. 
same width and height but instead of an image it's only a blank one.